# @zxing/ngx-scanner - Is there any simplified way to use this package to scan barcodes?

Tags: angular, barcode, zxing

My angularCLI version is as below

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.9
Node: 8.9.1
OS: win32 x64
```

This  [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zxing/ngx-scanner/v/1.0.5) doesnt have a proper documentation of how to utilize the functionality. Could anyone help with any sample example from this package?
Also StackBlitz provided in the document is not working.

Comment: There's a Demo section on the referred link (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zxing/ngx-scanner/v/1.0.5#demo) where you can, not only see a live demo on StackBlitz, but also the see the steps on how to use this package on your own app. You probably also should remove the version from the URL, in order to see its latest release (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zxing/ngx-scanner#demo).

Comment: You can also take a look at [this StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zxing-ngx-scanner) where you can see actually working code and play with it to understand how the component works.

Answer (score 7):

1. Install `@zxing/ngx-scanner` via NPM or Yarn, I'll presume you know how to do that.
2. Add the `ZXingScannerModule` to your `AppModule` (or any other where you wanna use it):

```
import { ZXingScannerModule } from '@zxing/ngx-scanner';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ZXingScannerModule,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent /*, other components */],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. Add the component to your template code and set the property `scanSuccess` to receive successful decoding results:

```
<zxing-scanner (scanSuccess)="onCodeResult($event)"></zxing-scanner>

<section class="results" *ngIf="qrResultString">
  <div>
    <small>Result</small>
    <strong>{{ qrResultString }}</strong>
  </div>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="clearResult()">&times;</button>
</section>
```

4. Prepare your component's TS code to receive data and display it:

```
  qrResultString: string;

  clearResult(): void {
    this.qrResultString = null;
  }

  onCodeResult(resultString: string) {
    this.qrResultString = resultString;
  }
```

5. You got it.

That's the easier way to use it, written using the version 1.7.2. Take a look at [this StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zxing-ngx-scanner-sw2r9h?file=projects%2Fzxing-scanner-demo%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) (please ignore Material components, they're not needed).

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Wiki](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner/wiki/Getting-Started) and this [blog](https://medium.com/swlh/scanning-barcode-or-qr-code-in-an-angular-app-with-zxing-9d3c8dfd5b96)

**Install following packages**

```
npm i @zxing/browser@latest --save
npm i @zxing/library@latest --save
npm i @zxing/ngx-scanner@latest --save
```

**Add import statement in app.module**

```
import { ZXingScannerModule } from '@zxing/ngx-scanner'
```

**Add zxing-scanner element in your component html**

```
<zxing-scanner></zxing-scanner>
```